# Execution failed for task ':tipsi-stripe:generateDebugRFile' Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.4

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, stripe-payments, react-native-firebase

I am trying to implement *Tipsi-stripe* in my project, yet after attempting to link manually all the dependencies I am getting the following error

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tipsi-stripe:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':tipsi-stripe:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.4.
     Required by:
         project :tipsi-stripe
```

This is my android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.4' //Added by Antek
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.0') //Added by Antek
    ...
}
```

This is my android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30

        // googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0" // default: "+"
        firebaseVersion = "17.3.4" // default: "+"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'// <- Added this line

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        google() //Added by Antek

        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And the following are my (problem related) dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.4.1",
     "tipsi-stripe": "^9.0.0"
    }
```

How do I solve this error? I tried cleaning the *gradlew* with `gradlew clean`, however nothing seems to be working so far :(

Answer (score 0):

You may not have seen the news, but Stripe just release their own React Native SDK `stripe-react-native` ([github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native)) recently, currently in open beta.

I highly recommend you review that package and the associate guides (eg, [accept-a-payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native)) and shift your integration efforts towards that instead.